# React - framer-motion / hook inside loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, framer-motion

I'm using framer-motion and I have a list of animations (coming from Sanity CMS - I guess it actually doesn't matter).
I have to convert those style into some Motion value, but my problem is that I have to use the 'useTransform' hook inside a loop. And this breaks the app. Any idea how I could convert this hook?

```
import { SanityAnimation } from '@sonos-inc/web-lib-types'
import { MotionProps, useTransform, useViewportScroll } from 'framer-motion'

export const useSanityScrollAnimations = (
  scrollStart: number,
  scrollEnd: number,
  animations?: Array<SanityAnimation & { startOffset?: number }>
): MotionProps['style'] => {
  try {
    if (animations?.length) {
      return Object.fromEntries(
        animations.map((a) => {
          const { animation, direction, value } = a
        
          // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
          const { scrollYProgress } = useViewportScroll()

          // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
          const rawValue = useTransform(
            scrollYProgress,
            [scrollStart, scrollEnd],
            [direction === 'from' ? value : 0, direction === 'to' ? value : 0]
          )

          // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
          const percent = useTransform(rawValue, (val) => `${val ?? 0}%`)

          return [animation, percent]
        })
      )
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error in useSanityScrollAnimations:\n', e)
  }

  return {}
}
```

I would like to convert this code to work without breaking the rules of hook.